# Counting down with a For Loop

Tags: c

I'm currently learning C via K&R's "The C Programming Language". Theres an exercise (1-5) that wants me to convert Fahrenheit to Centigrade using a for loop but with the values for Fahrenheit to be displayed in a descending order from my specified maximum value for it. The previous exercise was the same idea but in ascending order (which I completed successfully). I tried to complete the descending order task and I get no output what so ever in the console.

I'm not sure why this isn't working (I hope its not so obvious its embarrassing!)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int fahrenheit;

    for(fahrenheit = 250; fahrenheit <= 0; fahrenheit -= 25)
    {
        printf("%3d degrees fahrenheit is %3.3f degrees celcius\n", fahrenheit, (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, 8 answers in 2 mins. Reputation hunters on the prowl.

Comment: @cdoubleplusgood; What about you dude? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `for` loop

```
for(fahrenheit = 250; fahrenheit >= 0; fahrenheit -= 25) // change to this
```

The initial value of `fahrenheit` is 250 and you want to calculate the corresponding celsius temperature until it remains greater than zero. Therefore, the test condition should be `fahrenheit >= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Your test condition in for loop is wrong. To get into the loop change

```
for(fahrenheit = 250; fahrenheit <= 0; fahrenheit -= 25)
```

to

```
for(fahrenheit = 250; fahrenheit >= 0; fahrenheit -= 25)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop confition is never true:

```
fahrenheit <= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to continue iteration if `fahreneit >= 0`.

Otherwise, if you write `fahreneit <= 0`, the check will be **False** at first iteration step, and the program will exit immediately and print nothing.

```
for(fahrenheit = 250; fahrenheit >= 0; fahrenheit -= 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int fahrenheit;

for(fahrenheit = 250; fahrenheit >= 0; fahrenheit -= 25)
    printf("%3d degrees fahrenheit is %3.3f degrees celcius\n", fahrenheit, (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32));

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to be saying if fahrenheit is greater than or equal to 0 not less than.